# How to get chevron to align to center of link tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and have a navbar with several links. The first few links have dropdown menus. On top of each dropdown menu I added a triangle turned upward pointing to the link you just clicked. The problem is, the links are of different lengths (BRANDS vs MEN'S WATCHES) and I want the triangle centered with the text. Since the triangle is done with CSS via the `:before` attribute on the `dropdown-menu`, I don't know how to center it according to the `li` with the `dropdown` class.

Bootply of my navbar: http://www.bootply.com/ebKpdebUKh

CSS for the triangle:

```
#main_navbar2 .dropdown-menu:before { position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #000;
  border-left: 9px solid transparent;
  content: '';}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering of "chevron" has been done by using JQuery.

Check complete example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/JRorOw?editors=1000)**

HTML:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="/brands.html" id="header-brands">BRANDS</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-6" role="menu">
           ---- Multi column section ----
      </ul>
    </li>
```

JS:

```
$('.dropdown-menu , .dropdown > a').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('a:first-child').addClass('menu-pointer')
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().find('a:first-child').removeClass('menu-pointer');
});
```

CSS:

```
#main_navbar2 .dropdown > a.menu-pointer:after {
  top: 34px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #000;
  border-left: 9px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 9px;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Enjoy :)

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks for the great, clean solution :)

Comment: Your Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has an accepted answer - but you do not need jquery for it - just CSS and you can get a triangle under he center of the link text. I created a dodgy little navmenu - and have an active link which shows a little triangle under the active (selected) menu link - and then on the hover over each of the links - the triangle will show under the link text - and centered to the li. All without jQuery - and a little css magic. I also put in a longer than usual link text to show that the css tringle is autiomatically centered on the li.

```css
.navLinks li{display:inline-block;list-style:none; text-decoration: none;padding:0 10px}
.navLinks li a, .navLinks li a:hover{text-decoration: none}

.navLinks li:hover:after,
.activeLink:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width:0 9px 9px;
  border-color: #006400 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -8px;
  top:5px;
  left: 50%;
  background: none;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="navLinks">
   <li class="activeLink"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">An Example of a long link text.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I just wanted something that keeps the triangle connected to the dropdown menu, and not the actual link itself. This is because some links do not have a dropdown menu associated with it and those don't need triangles.